# How to deploy code from Visual Studio Code to Azure Function App in private endpoint and VNet?

Tags: azure-functions

I have Azure Function Premium (Python) with private network and Vnet in Azure.

I cannot currently deploy to Azure with Visual Studio Code from workstation.

```
11.09.57 func-App-2-171221: Starting deployment...
11.09.57 func-App-2-171221: Creating zip package...
11.09.57 func-App-2-171221: Zip package size: 10 kB
11.09.58: Error:  Error 403 - Forbidden
The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access.
```

What is easiest way to build access to network access from my laptop to Function app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample shows how Azure Functions can connect to other Azure resources via a [private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview) connection. The sample uses an [Azure Functions Premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan) with [regional VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#regional-virtual-network-integration) to interact with Azure resources confined to a virtual network.

Below is the sample code for deploying the azure function code.

```
func azure functionapp publish [YOUR-FUNCTION-APP-NAME]
```

For complete information check the [Private end points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-functions-private-endpoints/connect-to-private-endpoints-with-azure-functions/) document.

Comment: I know how to publish code from VS Code, but there is network issues. Do I need Site to Point VPN or is it possible to open firewall?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `zip` of your `function app` which must contain all the files.
   For example in python the zip file should contain

- host.json
- local.settings.json
- requirements.txt
- your api folder
- .python_packages

2. Upload this zip file to `storage account`'s container of which your function app is using.
3. Create a `SAS` token for this blob. (make sure the blob is `private`)
4. Copy the `blob URL`.
5. Go to `Function app` -> `configuration` and add new `application settings`.
   key is `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` and value is `<blob SAS URL you copied>`.
6. `Save` and `restart` your function app.